# Change data onclick with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart in ChartJS with euro's values. I'd like to be able to change the data in $.

The Euro Chart works well but I'm not able to change the datas.

My Chart:

```
   <canvas id="myChart" width="820" height="650"></canvas>
   let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;

   var dataEu = [{{{ cote_1989_eu_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_2004_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_2014_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_2017_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_actual_base_eu }}}];
   var dataUsd = [{{{ cote_1989_eu_base_usd }}}, {{{ cote_2004_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_2014_base_usd }}}, {{{ cote_2017_base_usd }}}, {{{ cote_actual_base_usd }}}];
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
         labels: ["1989", "2004", "2014", "2017", "2019"],
            datasets: [
               {
                  spangaps: true,
                  label: 'Exceptionnel',
                  data: dataEu,
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  borderColor: '#00C853',
                  borderWidth: 4,
                  pointWidth: 3,
                  pointRadius: 5,
                  pointHoverRadius: 6,
                  pointBorderColor: '#FFF',
                  pointBackgroundColor: '#00C853',
                  pointBorderWidth: 1,
                  pointHitRadius: 100,
                  datalabels: {
                     display: false
                     }
                  }]}
});
```

How can I change the data afterwards, replacing dataEu by dataUsd, if I click on a radio button for example ?

```
if (radioButtonEu.checked = true) {
???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dataUs` and `dataEu` are arrays with values, you can access and change the data of your chart easily with javascript like this:

```js
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dataUs; // assuming dataUs is an array
```

After doing that you need to rerender the chart with

```
myChart.update();
```

Heres a fully functional [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/dcts/pen/abbEGwK). Feel free to manipulate and play around with it.